# How to fix startup error in MySQL in XAMPP?

Tags: mysql, xampp

When I run XAMPP and MySQL it gives "MySQL shutdown unexpectedly", I looked at other questions but they have different error logs, here is my error log. I have tried changing my back up folder and changing my port to 3307, but nothing seems to do anything. Thank you

```
2021-11-05 19:20:37 0 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2021-11-05 19:20:37 0 [ERROR] Aborting
2021-11-05 19:25:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2021-11-05 19:25:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2021-11-05 19:25:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2021-11-05 19:25:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2021-11-05 19:25:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2021-11-05 19:25:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2021-11-05 19:25:01 0 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence number 300342 in the system tablespace does not match the log sequence number 300360 in the ib_logfiles!
2021-11-05 19:25:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2021-11-05 19:25:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2021-11-05 19:25:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file '\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2021-11-05 19:25:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: File '\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2021-11-05 19:25:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2021-11-05 19:25:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.21 started; log sequence number 300360; transaction id 170
2021-11-05 19:25:02 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2021-11-05 19:25:02 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2021-11-05 19:25:02 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2021-11-05 19:25:02 0 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
```

Comment: Is MySQL already running from another startup process when you ran this? It seems likely, because something is already using TCP3306. Try to connect to localhost 3306.

Comment: How would I connect to localhost 3306?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL was running in the background, go into task manager and find the running process and click end task then try again. MySQL was not starting due to it being run in the background.